# Visual Studio 2008 - Winforms Toolbox items gone

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbox

For whatever reasons, suddenly, all the usual tabs in the `Toolbox` of my Visual Studio 2008 (SP1, Prof.) are gone :-(

I only have stuff like `WPF Interoperability`, `Visual Basic PowerPacks` and so forth left. Where did all the usual tabs go?? Can't even add a button and a label anymore!

Tried to repair VS2008, run `devenv.exe` with `/setup`, `/resetskippkgs` and a few more command line options, and even re-installed the whole thing from my ISO file - no luck......

Any ideas?? What am I missing? Yes, I'd love to move to VS2010 - but I still need to be able to use my VS2008 for my Winforms apps...... any hints would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be several things involved depending on the particular defect - the most common cause seems to be a messed toolbox cache, see [Tip: Missing controls in Toolbox - Visual Studio 2008](http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2007/12/tip-missing-controls-in-toolbox-visual.html).

This tip has been confirmed several times already and is included in the [Toolbox Missing Controls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/490c9f52-f0c3-4fd3-9770-b8be9e0fd9d9) thread too, where you can find several other suggestions as well in case it doesn't address your problem.